# Topbar menu of SO business doesn’t work on blog page

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, stackoverflow-business

On the [blog page of Stack Overflow business](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/blog) topbar menu doesn’t work, i.e. tapping does nothing:

> [image: blog]

Works as expected on other pages, e.g. Talent:

> [image: talent]

This menu is only shown when the width of the page is too small to fit the menu icons.

Comment: Happens only on mobile, edited to reflect it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's not true. Just adjust your browser window to about half-width or less and you'll see it. I edited to address this.

Comment: @Laurel I see. Using Chrome dev tools to emulate mobile, didn't think to just resize.

Comment: Cross-site Duplication : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344470/2451726

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2018-01-07:** Ok, I believe this is *actually* fixed now.  There were three different js scripts attempting to show/hide the menu and they were interfering with each other.  I believe I've updated the CMS so that only one script is actually in play on each of the pages.  Thanks again for submitting this!

**Update 2018-01-05:** Confirmed this is still an issue on other pages, including https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/case-studies

Retaging as `status-planned`

---

Thanks for reporting this issue. The menu has been fixed in the mobile view (it was fixed a while back, but we missed updating the status here -- sorry about that).

Comment: Bad fix. Other pages are broken now. E.g. [here](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/case-studies).

Comment: @älёxölüt you are correct -- reopening the issue.